# django-extensions graph_models returns "no such option"

Tags: django, pygraphviz, django-extensions

- Django 1.7
- django-extensions installed and configured
- pygraphviz installed

When attempting to run `graph_models` it always fails with `manage.py: error: no such option:`

Example:

```
python manage.py graph_models -a -g -o django_schema.png
Usage: manage.py graph_models [options]

Creates a GraphViz dot file for the specified app names. You can pass multiple app names and they will all be combined into a single model. Output is usually directed to a dot file.

manage.py: error: no such option: -a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the docs: http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

> Compatibility with versions of Python and Django
>   We follow the Django guidelines for supported Python and Django versions. See more at Django Supported Versions
>
> This might mean the django-extensions may work with older or unsupported versions but we do not guarantee it and most likely will not fix bugs related to incompatibilities with older versions.
>
> **At this time we test on and thrive to support valid combinations of Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, pypy and pypy3 with Django versions 1.8 and 1.9.**

Upgrade Django to 1.8 or maybe use an older version of django-extensions.

Comment: Thanks, and damnit... I even looked at the docs to check version support. For anyone looking, the last version to support Django 1.7 is `1.6.7`.

Comment: This helped me to find out why `shell_plus` didn't work